# Difference between "das Klima" and "das Wetter"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, meaning

I am trying to understand the difference between the words *Klima* and *Wetter*. In my language (Italian) they can be both translated as "weather".
But something makes me guess that in German is not exactly the same. I would like to know how to use them correctly.

I guess that maybe when you talk about the weather forecast, you would use *Wetter* and maybe when you describe the weather in a certain area in general you would say *Klima*.
Am I right? Is it correct?

Comment: Nenn einen Klimaforscher *Wetterfrosch* und er wird Dir den Unterschied erklären. (Call a climate researcher weather man and he will explain the difference to you.)

Comment: http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clima

Comment: It's not precisely an answer to your question, but since it's the same in English, here's a rather cute explanation of the difference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBdxDFpDp_k -

Comment: Da quello che so io, la differenza tra "il clima" e "il tempo" spiegato nella risposta di Em1 esiste anche in italiano. (AFAIK the difference between "climate" and "weather" explained in Em1's answer exists in Italian as well)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft as a Klimaforscher who studied Wetterkunde as well - this hits home XD

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right.

*Wetter* describes the weather condition at a particular time.

> Das Wetter ist heute gut.
>   Das Wetter soll nächste Woche nicht so gut sein.

*Klima* (*climate*) describes the regular pattern of weather conditions (insolation, temperature, humidity, ...) of a particular place.

> Das ganze Jahr über herrscht ein mildes Klima.
>   Im Winter dagegen herrscht ein raues Klima

As in English, *Klima* also describes the atmosphere in a particular place

Answer (score 3):

One should differentiate between *Klima*/*Wetter*/*Atmosphäre*.

As @Em1 already explained, they are two different names for the same thing over different times/instances.

When we talk about the state of the outside **now/in few days/predicting**, we then talk about weather (**das Wetter**).

When we talk about the state of a **city/country/region/planet** over a period of time, we talk about climate (**Das Klima**).

When we talk about the feelings of some places, speaking of something else than weather/cold-hot/sunny-cloudy, like when there is some discussion about something, and the people start shouting, here we talk about **Atmosphäre**, then you could say:

> Die Atmosphäre ist angespannt. (The situation is tense).

Answer (score 3):

Man spricht von arktischem, tropischen, mediterranen und gemäßigtem Klima und meint damit verschiedene Arten, wenn man das Wetterverhalten über große Zeiträume betrachtet. Wetter ist bezogen auf einen oder ein paar Tage. Man spricht von Klimaerwärmung, die in allen Klimazonen spürbar sind, d.h. in den tropischen Gebieten wird es noch heißer im Durchschnitt und in der Arktis schmelzen die Gletscher, wodurch die Meeresspiegel steigen.